# WinForms Application not opening on other computers

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress-windows-ui

I have made a WinForms application that uses DevExpress (trial) but some of my friends can open it but some others can't. You can find the source here: https://github.com/JujharSingh/Exploit-Studio
I have also made sure that I didn't delete any DLL files while packaging.

Comment: In your `Exploit Studio.csproj` you have `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>`. Can you check for the systems it did not work if they have turned on the feature for this framework if it is even installed.

Comment: I made sure they downloaded .net framework 4.6.1

Comment: Well then, add loggers at places where you think it might break while initializing the controls for your UI. Check for the error messages received if any and update your question with the messages. Debugging this way will not be easier to crack down the real issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you right click on all the required files in solution explorer and include them so when you publish your project, they're deployed with the project.
[image]

Also make sure you've the following option configured correctly:
[image]

You wouldn't have to worry about .Net framework version as the published setup automatically installs missing .Net files.

Finally, goto your project Properties -> Publish -> Application Files and mark the required files as required and include them:

[image]

And on the same page, tick the required prerequisites:
[image]

Finally, make sure you're giving them the published version, not the copied executable file. Hope this helps

Comment: But then how do you explain: "but some of my friends can open it but some others can't"

Comment: @praty some of your friends might have the latest (or the version of .Net you've chosen for your application) installed. In the same context, they may already have the missing prerequisites or files on their systems through some update or through some other software's installation

Comment: i do that normally before redistributing my applications

Comment: Oh i forgot to require one dll OOPS accepting answer nvm still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your network path to the database is correct in the new computer.